# Parsing xml feed using YQL and jQuery doesn't work in IE 10+11

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm using [YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) in order to parse a cross-domain news feed.

I have created a script which loops the items like this:

```
getFeed();

function getFeed() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20rss%20where%20url%20%3D%20'http%3A%2F%2Fqz.com%2Ffeed%2F'",
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml) {
      console.log(xml);
      $(xml).find('item').each(function() {
        var title = $(this).find('title').html();
        var link = $(this).find('link').html();

        $("#feed2 > ul").append('<li><a href="' + link + '" target="_blank">' + title + '</a></li>');
      });
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed');
    }
  });
}
```

It works as intended in Edge, Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE 10 + 11.

What am I missing - and can it be fixed?
See [JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0z7hhvdL/3/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a whirl, I got it working in IE, and added some error handling...

```
getFeed();

function getFeed() {
    var strURL = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20rss%20where%20url%20%3D%20%27http%3A%2F%2Fqz.com%2Ffeed%2F%27"

    var service = $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        async: true,
        url: strURL,
        dataType: "xml",
            timeout: 30000
    });
    service.done(function (data) { feedComplete(data); });
    service.fail(function (jqXHR, strStatus) { feedFail(jqXHR, strStatus); });
    return false; // not a submit.
}

function feedComplete( xml ) {
   console.log(xml);
      $(xml).find('item').each(function() {
        var title = $(this).find('title').text();
        var link = $(this).find('link').text();

        $("#feed2 > ul").append('<li><a href="' + link + '" target="_blank">' + title + '</a></li>');
      });
}

function feedFail( jqXHR, strStatus ) {
    var strError = $(jqXHR.responseText).find( "description").text();
  $("#feed2 > ul").append('<li>' + strError + '</li>');

}
```

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for taking your time to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Strange thing... it turns out that changing html() to text() fixes the issues in IE 10 + 11:

```
var title = $(this).find('title').text();
var link = $(this).find('link').text();
```

Comment: I came across the same thing while cooking up my solution above.